# How to turn off daylight saving time on my phone?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia-640-xl

My country stopped using daylight saving time. My mobile network operators fixed that when I check for time via USSD codes while Windows Phone insists that we still use DST.

Is it possible to get Windows 10 Mobile to retrieve time only from my mobile network operators?

Comment: Just checking: is simply turning off the automatic time updates an acceptable option? The phone is quite good at keeping time even without an external source (and you wouldn't even have to set it forward and then back again every year!) so that should work. I can tell you how to do that. Otherwise, wait for an update, I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a month Microsoft decided to solve the issue with a new Windows version 10.0.10586.545 So I have to turn back on the automatic date and time setting so the time is reported correctly.

@CBHacking: Thanks for the tip.